# How to digital signature and sign xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cryptography, digital-signature

I am working on zatca simplified invoice using asp.net core 2.2, now i am facing problem in sign xml.
private key is generated from zatca sdk using below command
**(fatoora -csr -csrconfig csr-config-example.properties)**.

I have generated signature value from the hash of invoice and private key and assign it to its required field using xpath <ds:SignatureValue>,
after this generate the sign hash from SignedProperties of xml and pass it to <ds:DigestValue> 2nd reference of <ds:SignedInfo> but when invoice generates and check validation here (https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/TestXML) it throw errors of **(wrong xadesSignedPropertiesDigestValue and wrong signature Value)**

```
// this code if use to generate the signature value
     public static string SignDataWithECPrivateKey(byte[] data, byte[] privateKey)
     {
         ECPrivateKeyParameters keyParams = GetECPrivateKeyParameters(privateKey);
         ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withECDSA");
    
         signer.Init(true, keyParams);
         // Initialize for signing
         signer.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);
         byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
    
         return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
     }
    
     private static ECPrivateKeyParameters GetECPrivateKeyParameters(byte[] privateKey)
     {
         try
         {
             var privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKey);
             if (privateKeyInfo is ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPrivateKeyParameters)
             {
                 return ecPrivateKeyParameters;
             }
             else
             {
                 throw new Exception("Invalid EC private key format.");
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             throw new Exception("Error parsing EC private key: " + ex.Message);
         }
     }
    
    
           public static string DigitalSignature(string invoiceHash)
         {
             byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MIGNAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKBHYwdAIBAQQgH1/NUMqrSQLPiraQBpnHiNMjUOkSy/Re2qJpCHaPwfigBwYFK4EEAAqhRANCAAROmIO4u1eYiWqnVRwHzeKBDe4IOEiYsx8Gviqy1YGPuAMlpjWBEPncU/uFuFaNuNMErtTn8me8MI52QQN9uKoS");
        
             byte[] _invoiceData = Convert.FromBase64String(invoiceHash);
        
             return SignDataWithECPrivateKey(_invoiceData, privateKeyBytes);
         }
// end
```

<---- This code will generate Hash Of invoice sign properties (#xadesSignedProperties) --->

```
  public static string DigestMethod(string inputString)
  {
      // Create an instance of the SHA-256 hash algorithm
      using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
      {
          byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);

          // Calculate the hash (digest) of the input
          byte[] hashBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

          string hashHex = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

          return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashHex));
      }
  }

    public static MemoryStream CanonicalizeXml(string transformedXml)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(transformedXml)))
        {
            //converting xml to standard format
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0
            var canonicalizer = new XmlDsigC14NTransform(false);
            canonicalizer.LoadInput(memoryStream);
            var canonicalizedXml = canonicalizer.GetOutput() as MemoryStream;
            return canonicalizedXml;
        }
    }

    public static string GenerateSignHash(string inputXml)
    {
        var canonicalizedXml = InvoiceHashHelper.CanonicalizeXml(inputXml);
        return ECDSASigner.DigestMethod(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(canonicalizedXml.ToArray()));
    }

using xpath i fetch following xml 
/*<xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                    <xades:SigningTime>2023-10-25T15:28:31</xades:SigningTime>
                                    <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                        <xades:Cert>
                                            <xades:CertDigest>
                                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                <ds:DigestValue>Y2U5MzY5MTFiOTA4NTc0YmI2NjExNDFlMzBkNmM2YTljZWMxYjRlZDFmYWE3NjE1NjVlNDQzNjA3ODdkYzZjZQ==</ds:DigestValue>
                                            </xades:CertDigest>
                                            <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>2475382889481219846080454947234981286678397371</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                            </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                        </xades:Cert>
                                    </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                            </xades:SignedProperties>*/

and pass it **GenerateSignHash** Method

//xmlDoc is complete xml template of simplified invoice in which i do changes using xpath
// x509certificate pem fromat = "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";
 private static void SigninHash(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
 {
     byte[] cert = Convert.FromBase64String(GlobalXmlSetting.Cert);
     var x509 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
     var certInfo = new ECDSASigner().GetCertificateInfo(x509);

   //setnodevalue is custom 
     xmlDoc.SetNodeValue(SigningTimeXpath, certInfo.SignTime);
     xmlDoc.SetNodeValue(CertHashXpath, certInfo.CertHash);
     xmlDoc.SetNodeValue(CertIssuerXpath, certInfo.CertificateIssuer);
     xmlDoc.SetNodeValue(CertSerialNumberXpath, certInfo.CertificateSerialNumber);

     var _xml = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(SignedPropXpath).OuterXml;

     var signHash = ECDSASigner.GenerateSignHash(_xml);
     var signatureValue = ECDSASigner.DigitalSignature(_currentHash);
     xmlDoc.SetNodeValue(DigitalSignatureXpath, signatureValue);
     xmlDoc.SetNodeValue(SignInPropertiesHashXpath, signHash);

     _qrCode = new TlvConverter().TestTlv(_currentHash, signatureValue);

     PopulateQRCode(xmlDoc, _qrCode);
 }
```

**example xml :-**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
                    <sac:SignatureInformation>
                        <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                        <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256" />
                                <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                    <ds:DigestValue>sZwHJNRoZHatRyJ31IHiwE8og5xfcCOwewQV/FQz09Y=</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                                <ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                    <ds:DigestValue>ZTE3MjRlYzYxOTI5ZDdjMGNlMGJkMmI2MGJiNTFiNzQzZTgxYTljZmNiZWExMDc0MmVhOTRjZGUwOTAwOTM1NQ==</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                            </ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:SignatureValue>MEUCIBRiUYVKGoAO9LQFuDQUaWZlJbtrZE/yMXLzhWEc02SeAiEAx1DJ/YU8aFyz/+NJTsMPzVB3PQOha9dc4LGxTGIq2gU=</ds:SignatureValue>
                            <ds:KeyInfo>
                                <ds:X509Data>
                                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                                </ds:X509Data>
                            </ds:KeyInfo>
                            <ds:Object>
                                <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">
                                    <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                        <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                            <xades:SigningTime>2023-11-01T16:16:17</xades:SigningTime>
                                            <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                                <xades:Cert>
                                                    <xades:CertDigest>
                                                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                                        <ds:DigestValue>Y2U5MzY5MTFiOTA4NTc0YmI2NjExNDFlMzBkNmM2YTljZWMxYjRlZDFmYWE3NjE1NjVlNDQzNjA3ODdkYzZjZQ==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                    </xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                        <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>2475382889481219846080454947234981286678397371</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                    </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                </xades:Cert>
                                            </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                        </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                    </xades:SignedProperties>
                                </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                            </ds:Object>
                        </ds:Signature>
                    </sac:SignatureInformation>
                </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>


    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>100012</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>a7a3abb8-0f26-43bd-9cf9-b028d62fb223</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2022-09-13</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>14:40:40</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0200000">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:Note languageID="ar">ABC</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>10</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">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</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:Signature>
        <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
    </cac:Signature>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">324223432432432</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName>testA</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>3454</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:PlotIdentification>1234</cbc:PlotIdentification>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>fgffA</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>RiyadhA</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>12345</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cbc:CompanyID>311111111101113</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Acme Widget’s LTD</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName>baaounA</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>fgffA</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>testA</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
    </cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">300.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">300.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">300.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">2300.00</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">2300.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">100</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">1000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">150.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">1150.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>item2</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">10.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">34.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">100</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">1000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">150.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">1150.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>item1</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">10.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">34.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine></Invoice>
```

Comment: @Topaco any ideal..

Comment: @har07 any idea..

Comment: @OpenSBR any idea..

Comment: @MSantos any idea..

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong data on your XML

```
<cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
    <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
    <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">34.00</cbc:Amount>
</cac:AllowanceCharge>

<cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
```

must be

```
<cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
```

for discount

Comment: Thanks for discount issue notification, but the main problem i am  facing is digital signature and sign xml

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this ? facing same issue

Comment: @user1858884 not now if you have solved it plz let me know thanks

Comment: @user1858884 I have resolved this issue using zatca sdk, sdk have lib folder where you can find .net and java project solution

Answer (score 1):

After working two weeks on the issue, It get resolved by applying following changes in the XML File before validation.

```
 public void SetDigistProperty(string XMLFilePath, string Certificate, string PrivateKey)
    {
        XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XMLDoc.Load(XMLFilePath);
        string STR = SharedUtilities.GetNodeInnerXML(XMLDoc, Zatca.EInvoice.SDK.Utilities.ConfigurationManager.ConfigurationManager.SIGNED_PROPERTIES_XPATH).Replace(" />", "/>").Replace("></ds:DigestMethod>", "/>");
        var SIGNED_Properities = SharedUtilities.EncodeToBase64(SharedUtilities.HashSha256AsString(STR.Replace("\r", "")));
        SharedUtilities.SetNodeValue(XMLDoc, Zatca.EInvoice.SDK.Utilities.ConfigurationManager.ConfigurationManager.SIGNED_Properities_DIGEST_VALUE_XPATH, SIGNED_Properities);
        XMLDoc.Save(XMLFilePath);
    }
```

**Please Note:**

1. I am using ZATCA SDK 3.3.1 version for signing process
2. Here I am passing the Singed XML File which having UBL Extensions
   Tags
3. Forget about the Web Validator in B2C it will give you error anyway
   but after applying the above changes. Offline and ZATCA API
   validation got passed without any errors